# how to scrape a website with pages that dont affect the url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What I'd like to do is to scrape a Clash of Clans players profile site from clashofstats.com for instance: https://www.clashofstats.com/players/captain-morgan-L9YJUPY22/history/log

to get an approximation of the last and first time played based on the logged clan activity, first of which I have already implemented with the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.clashofstats.com/players/captain-morgan
L9YJUPY22/history/log')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

end_dates = soup.find_all(class_="end date")

last_played = str(end_dates[0]).replace("<span class=\"end date\">", "")
last_played = last_played.replace(",", "")
last_played = last_played.replace("</span>", "")

print(f"Last  time played| {last_played}")
```

Output:
`Last  time played| Sep 30 2022`
(weird format is to match the rest of the code)

Now back to my question, the problem comes with the first time played. clashofstats has multiple pages of logged clans, but when going to the last page (where the first date is) the url doesn't change and nor does the source code. I can only see changes from the dev Tools, but how can I direct, preferably using BeautifulSoup, to that last page and get the date?, if that is even possible.

Comment: `requests` is downloading static HTML (one and done). It does not "browse" a site to change the "source" or url. Perhaps you should be using selenium instead?

Comment: In general it sounds like what you're looking for is a "headless browser", which is more than just an HTML parser.  It's essentially an entire browser engine, to execute JavaScript and update the DOM and all that, that you'd interact with in code.

Comment: So if I'm getting this right, there is no way to accomplish what I wanted with requests?
Then also what would it look like using selenium ?

Comment: @Nuspli with selenium you can pretty much interact with the site as you would directly. So you could "click" on the 2nd page and then "select" or "find" all the end_dates there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 'next' and page button are not hyperlinked and the site doesn't seem to be loading the data via any easy-to-find APIs, I expect it would take a horribly convoluted process of requesting and parsing scripts to retrieve this one date from the last page.

Instead, you could use selenium to click the last page button [(`2`) in this case] and then get the last date. (If you haven't ever used selenium before, I found [this](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/) to a be a very helpful starting point.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromeDriver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
# I just copied the exe file to the same folder as this py file
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver_path)

tag = "L9YJUPY22"  # your player tag without '#'

driver.get('https://www.clashofstats.com/players/' + tag + '/history/log')

start_dates = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.start.date')
end_dates = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.end.date')
page_btns = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.v-pagination__item')

try:
    clan = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.v-list-item__title.text--secondary.font-italic').get_attribute(
    'innerText')
except:
    clan = "something else"

if start_dates[0].get_attribute('innerText') == end_dates[0].get_attribute('innerText') or clan == "Not in any Clans":
    # basically the inactivity time can't really be seen from just the clan, so it only works on
    # players that don't have a clan. this is sometimes displayed weird by the website, thus this logic
    last_played = start_dates[1].get_attribute('innerText')
    # only start date is available when turning inactive
else:
    last_played = end_dates[0].get_attribute('innerText')  # in a normal case this is "today"

# see if there are more pages
if len(page_btns) > 0 and len(end_dates) > 0:
    page_btns[-1].click()  # click the last page_btn
    start_dates = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.start.date')  # update start dates

first_played = start_dates[-1].get_attribute('innerText')  # get last start date

print(f"First time played| {first_played}")
print(f"Last  time played| {last_played}")

driver.close()  # else the window stays open and your program keeps running
```

Output:

```
First time played| Sep 8, 2020
Last  time played| Oct 1, 2022
```

This should work standalone for any number of pages.

Comment: I am getting an error:

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css_selector'           
As I was trying to find some solutions yesterday I faced the same problem... is something wrong with my selenium version?

Comment: pycharm only gives the methods "find_element(self, by, value)" and "find_element(self, by, value)"

Comment: I tried using : end_dates = driverC.find_elements("css_selector", 'span.end.date') but only got another error : selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator

Comment: Sorry, I should probably stop doing it like that - some versions don't recognize it [I think mine is not updated yet maybe so it still works]

Comment: Try adding `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` to your imports, and then change to `driverC.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.end.date')`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, all fine now with selenium. However, first time played as output doesnt match whats on the website and the date still comes from the first page

Comment: So I found the problem, first off all the print for First time played should also be at the bottom in case it gets updated and secondly replace span.end.date in line 24 with span.start.date and also change the variable name

Comment: @Nuspli sorry again, I mixed them up - and didn't notice that there were 2 different date classes. I'm glad you figured it out. ( you don't need it anymore, but I've edited my answer. again ).

Comment: Sorry but you still got the dates wrong, it's a little complicated for me too. Last time played is definetely today, I also got to work out something there as the latest log will always show the current date...

Comment: Ok finally found a working solution, is there a way for me to edit your answer or should I make my own ?

Comment: There should be `Share` , `Edit` ,  `Follow` and `Flag` buttons [that look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWY7I.jpg) just above these comments, but if you don't see the edit button (or even if you do, but just want to post separately) I'd very much appreciate if you edited in/ added the final solution!